# Getting Error No.: 424 object required upon using String.Length in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am want to get length of a string. But I am getting error  **Error No.: 424 object required** .

```
Dim Start as String
Dim LengthofStart as Integer

If Start <> "" Then

    MsgBox ("Going to calculate length  now::")
    lengthofstart = Start.Length 
    MsgBox ("The lenght of start is " & LengthofStart)

End If
```

The error is appearing when I get the length of string "`Start`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Len(Start)` instead

```
lengthofstart = Len(Start)
```